# SQL BigQuery - Use WITH view in 'IN' clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Does BigQuery support the usage of WITH views in the 'IN' clause?

```
WITH validyears as (SELECT Year FROM movies WHERE Year > 2005)

SELECT * 
FROM movies 
WHERE Year IN validyears
```

I get "Unrecognized name" error.

Comment: Why not `SELECT * FROM movies WHERE year > 2005`?

Comment: I have the subquery "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE year > 2005" on two parts of my original query and want to deduplicate it with an "WITH" statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```sql
WITH validyears as (SELECT Year FROM movies WHERE Year > 2005)

SELECT * 
FROM movies 
WHERE Year IN (Select year from validyears)
```